# React.js: attach event from parent to children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

as shown in the example below, I'd like MyComponent to dynamically attach an "onClick" event to its children. The onClick event should fire alertView that should be able to call the clicked element method "getValue".

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2g638bp8/

How to do this? Thanks

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    alertValue: function () {
        // RETRIEVE THE CHILD HERE
        alert(child.getValue());
    },
    render: function () {
        var children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (c, index) {
            return React.addons.cloneWithProps(c, {
                ref: 'child-' + index
            });
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var MySubComponent = React.createClass({
    getValue: function () {
        return this.props.val;
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.val}</div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(
    <div>
        <MyComponent>
            <MySubComponent val="1" />
            <MySubComponent val="2" />
            <MySubComponent val="3" />
        </MyComponent>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't call methods on child components in React. You can only set properties. (The `child` is actually a `ReactElement` which contains information about the class and associated properties. It is not an instance of the component you created).

So, you could think about this a [slightly different](http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/Ld39pms7/) way and move the `onClick` to the `MySubComponent`:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    onHandleGiveValue: function (value) {
        alert(value);
    },
    render: function () {
        const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => React.cloneElement(child, { onGiveValue: this.onHandleGiveValue.bind(this) }));
        return (
            <div>
                {children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var MySubComponent = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function() {
        this.props.onGiveValue(this.props.val);
    },
    getValue: function () {
        return this.props.val;
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div onClick={ this.handleClick } >{this.props.val}</div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(
    <div>
        <MyComponent>
            <MySubComponent val="1" />
            <MySubComponent val="2" />
            <MySubComponent val="3" />
        </MyComponent>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

By doing that, your code can pass the current value as an event to the parent component. I've created a new event from the `MySubComponent` class named `onGiveValue`. That for now just passes the value from `this.props.val`. But, it could of course be anything.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer - is it now worth updating it and your fiddle to use `React.cloneElement` instead..? (due to `cloneWithProps` being deprecated)

Comment: Thanks @adarren, now changed.

Comment: Why return the enclosing div?

Comment: @TheDembinski-because their question had that structure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass the parent callback to the subComponent, one dont need a reference for the child component.
2. React prefers composition design pattern, So your parent component should contains those three subComponent.
   JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68vt3umg/

   ```
   var MyComponent = React.createClass({
   handleChildClick: function (e, childValue) {
      alert(childValue);
   },
   render: function () {
       return (
           <div>
             <MySubComponent val="1" onSubClicked={this.handleChildClick}/>
             <MySubComponent val="2" onSubClicked={this.handleChildClick}/>
           </div>
       );
   }});

   var MySubComponent = React.createClass({
     getValue: function () {
       return this.props.val;
     },
     handleOnClick: function (e, value) {
       this.props.onSubClicked(e, this.props.val);
     },
     render: function () {
       return (
           <div onClick={this.handleOnClick}>{this.props.val}</div>
       );
     }
   });

   React.render(
     <div>
       <MyComponent />
     </div>,
     document.getElementById('container')
   );
   ```

Comment: How is this different than my answer?

Comment: There are no children passed to `MyComponent` which is what the OP wanted